# Prove that : $\prod_{cyc}(2a^2+2b^2-c^2)\prod_{cyc}(a+b-c)\leq a^2b^2c^2(a+b+c)^3$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, geometric-inequalities

Let $a,b,c$ be the sides for given triangle $ABC$ , then the following inequality true :

$$\prod_{cyc}(2a^2+2b^2-c^2)\prod_{cyc}(a+b-c)\leq a^2b^2c^2(a+b+c)^3$$

Actually **Michael Rozenberg** gave a nice solution but I am looking for a different approach like using some known inequality if possible

---

**solution of Michael Rozenberg**

let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, $$\prod_{cyc}(2a^2+2b^2-c^2)=\prod_{cyc}(2(a^2+b^2+c^2)-3c^2)=$$
$$=8(9u^2-6v^2)^3-12(9u^2-6v^2)^3+18(9u^2-6v^2)(9v^4-6uw^3)-27w^6=$$
$$=27(-w^6+2(3u^2-2v^2)(9v^4-6uw^3)-4(3u^2-2v^2)^3).$$
Also, $$\prod_{cyc}(a+b-c)=\prod_{cyc}(3u-2c)=27u^3-54u^3+36uv^2-8w^3=$$
$$=-8w^3-27u^3+36uv^2.$$
Thus, we need to prove that $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where 
$$f(w^3)=u^3w^6-(-w^6+2(3u^2-2v^2)(9v^4-6uw^3)-4(3u^2-2v^2)^3)(-8w^3-27u^3+36uv^2).$$
But $$f''(w^3)=2u^3-2(-2w^3+2(3u^2-2v^2)(-6u))(-8)+$$
$$-(-8w^3-27u^3+36uv^2)(-2)=-4(157u^3-114uv^2+12w^3)<0,$$ which says that $f$ is a concave function.

Thus, it's enough to prove our inequality for an extreme value of $w^3$, which happens in the following cases.

1. $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.
   in this case the inequality is obvious;
2. $\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b-c)\rightarrow0^+$.

It's obvious again;

3. Two variables are equal.

Since our inequality is symmetric and homogeneous, it's enough to assume $b=c=1$.

Thus, $0<a<2$ and we need to prove that
$$a^2(a+2)^3\geq(2a^2+1)^2(4-a^2)a^2(2-a)$$ or
$$(a+2)^2\geq(2a^2+1)^2(2-a)^2$$ or
$$a+2\geq(2a^2+1)(2-a)$$ or
$$a(a-1)^2\geq0$$ and we are done!

---

**thanks**

Comment: Why are you essentially reposting [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3605636/prove-that-m-am-bm-c-leq-fracrs22)?

Comment: @CalvinLin I need learn from the great teacher of MSE like MicharlRozenberg  , im always search another way and solution!

Comment: I'd say to 1) Upvote/Accept his answer, 2) Ask him directly if he has a simpler way. I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @CalvinLin thank you very much sir , I'm waiting other what say! If I'm wrong I will deleted my question and leave MSE

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you have to leave MSE. I'm pointing out that the standard procedure here is to not post a duplicate of a question that you just posted. You are more likely to get feedback from anyone (like Michael) by directly asking them. (On another note, for questions that you posted in the past, if you find an answer helpful, please accept it.)

Comment: @CalvinLin I'm thankful to you for your advice , But knowing that I just wanted to learn!

Comment: @Roze flowers I see another way by hand, but it's still a hard solution. Say me please, where you took this inequality?

Comment: @Calvin Lin there is no problem with reposting a problem if you are looking for alternative proof and many users did it before. It's very frustrating to many people to see their posts get downvoted/closed for no good reason.